# Остановить процессы в Activity

Tags: android, java, generate

Есть код генератора звука

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.SeekBar.*;
import android.widget.EditText.*;
import android.widget.TextView.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import java.lang.*;

public class Generator extends Activity {

    private int duration = 5; // seconds
    private final int sampleRate = 8000;
    private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
    private double freqOfTone = 0; // hz

    private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.generator);

        Button generationbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generation);
        final SeekBar freqbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.freqbar);
        final TextView  freqedit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freqedit);

        freqedit.setText(String.valueOf(freqbar.getProgress()*240));
        freqOfTone=freqbar.getProgress()*240;
        freqbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChanged = 0;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                progressChanged = progress;
                freqOfTone = progressChanged*240;
                freqedit.setText(String.valueOf(progressChanged*240));
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });

        generationbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                genTone();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        playSound();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();

            }
        });

    }

    void genTone(){
        // fill out the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

        }
    }

    void playSound(){
        final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        audioTrack.play();
    }

}
```

После нажатия кнопки начинает генерироваться звук, но если во время работы генератора нажать кнопку назад, то он продолжает генерироваться. Как остановить процесс генерации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте объявить audioTrack как глобальную переменную и добавить метод:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    audioTrack.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```